# How can i get 3 random numbers as output from a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

Example i have a 10 items list like below,
test_list = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]
so my question is how can i get 3 random numbers as output, is there any way to get it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) for Python's `random` module?

Comment: nope i didn't but i was thinking to see documentation but in my area wasn't electricity so had to wait...!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by @MarkDickinson, you can use the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) in the Python standard library.

You can opt for different functions depending on whether you want the selection to be done *with or without replacement*.

In practical terms, do you want selections like `[1, 1, 7]` or `[5, 3, 5]` that contain multiple copies of a single source element to be possibilities?

```
>>> test_list = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]

>>> import random

# With replacement:
>>> random.choices(test_list, k=3)
[4, 9, 9]

# Without replacement:
>>> random.sample(test_list, k=3)
[8, 1, 2]
```